# ClCompile and Emscripten

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, emscripten

I had a error with a basic hello world from a set of examples from Emscripten/tests/msvc10

I have a error MSB4096 but i don't find the solution of the problem on visual Studio 2012.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(817,5): error MSB4096: The item "..\hello_world.c" in item list "ClCompile" does not define a value for metadata "ProgramDataBaseFileName".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ClCompile.ProgramDataBaseFileName), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.

Do you know the reason?

thanks

Comment: have you managed to solve this issue? it seems more like a vs-tool or vs2012 issue rather than causing by the managed code.

Comment: Hello, the problem is that Vs-tools doesn't function with VS 2012. I can use VS2010

Answer (score 0):

When trying to compile keep in mind 2 things:

1. Do no try to compile managed C++ code with emscripten.
2. the code is running in browser sandbox

The metadata stuff in your code seems really related to the first issue (managed code).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the 'Program Database File Name' (ProgramDataBaseFileName) Property in the VS C/C++ Options of your Project e.g. to '$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb'

ProgramDataBaseFileName exposes the functionality of the compiler's /Fd (Program Database File Name) option.

[MSDN ProgramDataBaseFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.VCCLCompilerTool_properties(v=vs.90).aspx)